# Python Regular Expressions finds nothing

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Trying to find certain tags in html code using Beautiful Soup 4. There are a tags like this:

```
<a href='obec.php?kod_obce=511226'>Ábelová</a>
```

in the html.

The problem is, that bs4 can't find these tags when I try to use `re.compile`.

Here is a part of the code:

```
obce = soup.findAll("a", attrs={'href':re.compile("obec.php?kod_obce.*")})
```

It finds nothing.

Have you any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You'll have to provide us with some sample data.

Comment: That's not a text but a text node. It is the *content* of the `a`  element.

Comment: See, now we have context; this is *not* a problem with the content of the tag but with your regular expression.

Comment: As a side note, you should invest the cost of a browser bookmark or maybe 200K of disk space on a good regular expression debugger. For example, see [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ywcnBWRoZozHeUOB). It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` is a special character for regular expressions: it means `p` or no character. Strings with a question mark are rejected. Use escaping:

```
r"obec.php\?kod_obce.*"
```

Comment: Better to write this as a raw string literal so you only need to escape the `?`, not also escape the escaping backslash.

Comment: @abarnert: modified. Better?

Comment: Yeah; too bad I already upvoted you, but I can upvote the comment too. :)